# SqlDataReader.GetGuid with column name c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

Is there a way to get a column by name and retain the SQL type information returned by `SqlDataReader`?

I only see `.GetGuid(int column)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no separate method to get a GUID (or any of the other types) by column name directly.

What you need to do is this:

```
Guid someguid = dr.GetGuid(yourDataReader.GetOrdinal("your-col-name"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always just cast the result of the `SqlDataReader`'s indexer:

```
Guid myGuid = (Guid)myDataReader["myColumnName"];
```

Comment: Is there any actual difference doing this? (it seems there isn't?)

Comment: Joining Paul's question here and adding: Could there be a performance improvement of one method over the other?